# Inserir endereço no formulário do meu site e retornar a posição do endereço no mapa automaticamente

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

Olá, estou com um mapa, google maps, que marca posições de lugares diversos. De um modo genérico eu gostaria de que, ao inserir o endereço no formulário do meu site, o local seja marcado no mapa sem que precise arrastar a posição no mapa, automatizar o posicionamento no mapa.

```html
<div class="col-md-12">
  <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBUMKHFlfDJ5cOq4ZqnaTtwaV99_zcLUSY&callback=initMap"></script>
    <script>
      function initMap() {
      var myLatLng = { lat: <%= @unit.coordinates[:latitude] %>, lng: <%= @unit.coordinates[:longitude] %> };

      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                center: myLatLng,
                scrollwheel: false,
                zoom: 15
              });

      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: myLatLng
              });
            };
    </script>
          <div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 200px; margin-bottom: 10px;"></div>
 </div>
```

Este mapa permite que arraste o ponto até onde eu desejar mas quero que quanto inserir o endereço no formulário ele posicione o ponto no mapa referente ao endereço.

Grato pela atenção!

Comment: Eu tenho código para isso mas é pelas coordenadas

Comment: pode ser que ajude, eu posso fazer um script de consulta de coordenadas e o retorno fica o endereço

Comment: Ok o que eu tenho está aqui: https://jsfiddle.net/tzhgLyz3/ ... Neste caso colocas o nome da zona para que o pino (inserido pelas coordenadas) fique com essa descrição. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9309251/google-maps-javascript-api-get-gps-coordinates-from-address, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652951/google-maps-api-get-coordinates-of-address Vê isto que pelos vistos é possivel retornar as coordenadas pelo endereço

Comment: Valeu, agora vou fazer um script para pegar as coordenadas do endereço e juntar com esse seu código.